# Best way to use support function in R to stay DRY

Tags: r, dry

While working on my first R package a noticed that when the package structure gets created in the man directory "man" there is a documentation file for each function/method in the code.

In order to stay DRY (don't repeat yourself) I used some functions as "auxiliary" functions in loops or iteration. How can I tell R that I do not want to provide any documentation for them given that they should not be called directly by the end user?!?!

Comment: Please read [section 1.1.3 of Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `roxygen2` and `devtools` packages to document your functions and build your package.

```
#' Function 1 Title
#'
#' Describe what function 1
#' does in a paragraph. This function
#' will be exported for external use because
#' it includes the @export tag.
#'
#' @param parameter1 describe the first parameter
#' @param parameter2 describe the second parameter
#' @examples
#' function1(letters[1:10], 1:10)
#' @export
function1 <- function(parameter1, parameter2) {
  paste(parameter1, parameter2)
}

#' Function 2 Title
#'
#' Description here. This will not 
#' be added to the NAMESPACE.
#'
#' @param parameter1
function2 <- function(parameter1) {
  parameter1
}
```

Once you have all your documentation, use the tools in the `devtools` package to build, document, and check your package. It will automatically update the man files and DESCRIPTION, and add / remove functions from the NAMESPACE.

```
document()
build()
check()
```

I also recommend using the `rbundler` package to control how you load packages.

Comment: You don't technically need devtools to make roxygen run (you can just use `roxygenize()` ) but it does make the process a little easier.  I mention this just because I've had some cases where `document()` failed to build everything for one reason or another but `roxygenize()` ran fine.

Comment: @Dason it's always appreciated if you [report those bugs](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues).

Comment: "and add / remove functions from the NAMESPACE": one of my biggest gripes. I will not let roxygen2 touch DESCRIPTION or NAMESPACE and use a wrapper with `roclets="rd"`.

Comment: @hadley - I would but I haven't actually taken the time to figure out any information that would make for a useful bug report.  At the moment it wouldn't be more than "document() didn't work but roxygenize() did"  which is far from useful.  The next time it occurs I'll try to take the time to gather some useful information.

Comment: @Dason thanks, it's appreciated.  I'd generally think it would be the opposite: `document()` will work in situations where `roxygenise()` doesn't (because of the effort devtools goes to set environment variables etc)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not export them via the NAMESPACE you are not expected to provide documentation.

Another (older) was is too simple create one, say, `internal.Rd` and define a bunch of `\alias{foo}, \alias{bar}, \alias{frob}` and that way codetools is happy too.

Comment: `internal.Rd`? Or are you using RMarkdown for your docs now? ;)

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Jojoshua-ulrich and @dirk-eddelbuettel

According to "Writing R Extensions":

> The man subdirectory should contain (only) documentation files for the objects in the package in R documentation (Rd) format. The documentation filenames must start with an ASCII (lower or upper case) letter or digit and have the extension .Rd (the default) or .rd. Further, the names must be valid in ‘file://’ URLs, which means9 they must be entirely ASCII and not contain ‘%’. See Writing R documentation files, for more information. Note that all user-level objects in a package should be documented; if a package pkg contains user-level objects which are for “internal” use only, it should provide a file pkg-internal.Rd which documents all such objects, and clearly states that these are not meant to be called by the user. See e.g. the sources for package grid in the R distribution for an example. Note that packages which use internal objects extensively should not export those objects from their namespace, when they do not need to be documented (see Package namespaces).

By the way, is there any convention to include comments in the code so that man grabs the function description, arguments description etc directly from the code?

Comment: There isn't a way to do exactly what you want.  But there is 'roxygen' which is a package that will allow you to generate the documentation based off of comments in your code (but you have to format the comments properly)